# Manipulating "filename" of file dialog opened using a "print to pdf" option

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have over a thousand e-mails that need to be converted to individual PDFs.  The code I've written is able to process the faux-print job up to the "Save PDF As..." Dialog Box.

I need to manipulate the filename in that dialog to the original filename.  I cannot find a way to post a string to the filename section of the dialogbox, since this is an unconventional method posting on a separate process.

How do I send this information to an active dialog window that is unrelated to the process the application is calling?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string folderIn = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"Z:\Files up to 3-6-13\");
        string folderOut = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\users\athomas\desktop\Output");

        string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(folderIn);

        foreach(var fileName in fileList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);

            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
            info.Verb = "Print";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(info);

            //  This is where I need to say something like
            //  SaveDialog.SaveAs(fileName.SafeFileName) 

            if(p.HasExited == false)
            {
                p.WaitForExit(1000);
            }


        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Since it is clear you are capable of writing code, get yourself a library that does what you want, and call that library.  Simulating user clicks is unreliable and difficult.  This code is similar to performing math by running "calc.exe" and clicking on buttons. :-)

Comment: What kind of files are these?

Comment: I don't know if there is a library that does what I want.  I've not found one that I can safely risk testing at the office...I'll keep looking though, your suggestion is definitely where I thought this would end.

These files are .msg from outlook.  They can't be compiled to PDF in the traditional fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking basically about hacking around, which means there is no safe way to do that. The possible way may look like this:

1) You enumerate windowses shown on the screen, via [EnumWindows](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html)

2) You use for every window [GetWindowText](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowText.html) to find a Title of the Dialog you are searching for.

3) Ocassionaly there may be more then one dialog, [Murphy's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) is always there, so may be even with the same title. You can *reduce* collision risk by

3.a Call [GetWindowLong](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowLong.html) with HWND of "dialog" you found

3.b Call [GetParent](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetParent.html) to get HWND of parent window, *that you already know*

If you can avoid or may not care about case of window style&title collision, just jump over point (3)

4) Once you found your dialog, run over its HWND [EnumChildWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html) to get all controls of it

5) Find the contrlol you interested in via some attribute (usually Class_ID)

6) Execute [SetWindowtext](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowText.html) to set the text you like.

As I said before, there are several places were this process can fail.
For example:

- You may happen to have multiple dialogs on the screen in the same moment
- You may download a new version of PDF processor, and in SaveAs dialog may have something changed, so your code will break.

But considering that you are hacking, you may assume your own risks.

An excellent tool, may be the best tool, for window investigation on Windows, is probably [Spy ++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx), which is available within visual studio installation.  Using it you can try to find some unique attributes of a textbox of that dialog where you want to put the text in. Having that in your hands you can reliably query dialog's children collection to find the textbox.

Comment: Thanks, Tigran.  I haven't messed with Spy++, but from the sounds of it, I may have no choice here.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to go through so many steps, but I'll do whatever it takes I suppose.

I'll let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Marked as the answer.  This was what (eventually) got me to the solution. Using APIs and libraries did not provide me with the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

After you mentioned .msg, I did a Google Search on the .msg file format and I was surprised to find it was well documented.  It is an OLESS file, and there are APIs for loading those.  I even found a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C) C# sample that was able to load an email I just saved from Outlook 2013!

It will be a bit of work since you will have to write code to "render" message how you see fit.  Ex: It gives you the body, the recipients, and the attachments.  You would have to decide what to do with the attachments and code that up.  Then find a PDF library.  But at least it is a programmatic solution, rather than relying on hacking the UI.

Also: A Google search for .MSG to PDF returned loads of tools to do this.  One is a forum post referring to an Adobe Product called "Acrobat PDFMaker" so maybe you don't even need to write code.

Comment: And as a side note, we own a license for PDF Maker, but it does not allow us to work with these files in the specific matter necessary (including maintaining original file name).  This is being employed for a law firm and I'm keeping it internal and simple to avoid any leak or break in the evidence trail...which is also why I can't just use any tool on the market.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post 2 answers.  I have a solution to the exact problem of prompting for the file.  These instructions vary slightly based on the version of Windows, but you will get the idea:

1. Add a new printer that uses PDF printer driver
2. When it asks for the "port" click "Add Port" then "Local Port"
3. Enter in a file name.  Ex: "C:\Users\Myself\MyPdf.pdf"
4. Complete the printing wizard as usual.

I tested this with the XPS printer and it worked

When you print to this printer, it writes to that exact file: No prompting!  You will have to monitor the file (I suggest FileSystemWatcher) or poll for when the file is closed or something like that.  After that, you can move the file elsewhere.